# Setting custom <OutputPath> in .NET Core (stop adding framework target)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core

In traditional .NET applications, it was possible to set a custom `<OutputPath>` of an assembly in the `.csproj` file (or via the project properties dialog). A path of e.g. `bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)` resulted in `bin\Debug\AnyCPU`.

I had the habit of setting those values independent of the current build configuration (in its own `ItemGroup`, together with `DocumentationFile`, etc).

When I'm setting up my configuration in the new .NET core `.csproj` like this...

```
<OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)</OutputPath>
<DocumentationFile>$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).xml</DocumentationFile>
```

..the following folder structure gets created:

```
bin\
  Debug\
    AnyCPU\
      MyAssembly.xml
      netstandard1.0\
        MyAssembly.exe
```

So it seems *msbuild*, or whatever automatically appends the `TargetFramework`, which is rather annoying.

Is there a way to truly customize the output path or disable this behavior?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can disable this behaviour by setting:

```
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
```

This behaviour originates from the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` (see [its source](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/cd25d6bbfc2aac61cc790c511900427ac64fdaa8/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets#L167-L174))

Comment: also, if you need it: `<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>`